# debian stretch missing do-rel.h after upgrade

Tags: debian, upgrade, chrome, mplayer, mpv

debian 9 `apt-get update;apt-get upgrade`
now mplayer, mpv and chromium seg fault with similar errors; gdb /usr/bin/mpv says

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   elf_dynamic_do_Rela (skip_ifunc=, lazy=, nrelative=, relsize=, reladdr=, map=0x7f8cfd16e3c0)
>       at do-rel.h:112
>   112     do-rel.h: No such file or directory.

and `gdb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium`

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   elf_dynamic_do_Rela (skip_ifunc=, lazy=, nrelative=, relsize=, reladdr=, map=0x7ff35df753d8)
>       at do-rel.h:112
>   112     do-rel.h: No such file or directory.

Asked debian [what provides do-rel.h](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=do-rel.h) and it says

> Sorry, your search gave no results

How do I install do-rel.h ? (Or fix this?) reinstall of mpv and chromium did not fix, (and oddly firefox and google-chrome are still working.)

> Source list

```
#/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main contrib non-free
# and in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

p.s. (I asked on stackoverflow and was told to post here.)

Comment: Do you have a list of the packages that were updated with your latest upgrade?

Comment: `do-rel.h` is part of the C library. It sounds like you have a corrupted library which is used by those three programs... If you install the `glibc` debug symbols you’ll be able to get better output from `gdb` (see [How to get a meaningful backtrace](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToGetABacktrace) for details).